# Eloquent many to many relationship access table column value from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, relation

I have two models:

```
class Order extends Eloquent 
{
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function Product()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
}
```

and the second one is:

```
class Product extends Eloquent 
{
    public function Order()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Order');
    }
}
```

My question is how can i access a value of second table column using pivot table:

product table:

```
id
title
image
```

order table:

```
id
status
```

pivot table(order_product):

```
id
product_id
order_id
```

I need to access title column of products from orders. for example if a user orders many products in one order I can fetch all product title and show theme.
I don't like use join , instead I like to use Laravel functionality itself.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: What have you named the pivot table, it should be named `order_product` if you are using the default the eloquent expects, otherwise you have to override it when defining the relation.

Comment: yep, I named it order_product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
$orders = Order::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate($page_number);

foreach($orders as $item){
  foreach($item->product as $item){
     {{$item->title}}<br>
  }
}
```

I can access products from order.

Comment: I would recommend using `with()` to prevent the N+1 query problem, look here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading